# Should I Save a Users Primary Key on Device When they Sign Up?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm for IOS , and I have a Tableview Controller that shows all the Items a User is selling. Should I save the Primary Key so I could use:

let user = realm.object(ofType: UserProfile.self, forPrimaryKey: (UserProfile.primaryKey()))

To get the Realm Object of the user that's signed in and then filter out the books he's selling ( The object UserProfile is Linked to another Object called Textbook in a one to Many relationship. )

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Typically for storing things such as passwords or private keys, it's recommended to use the [iOS keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Comment: @Kevin, And could I use such in Xcode? So when the user signs up, I would catch the Username they made (which is the Primary Key) using the IOS Keychain, and then use the IOS Keychain to  use the ForPromaryKey method to get the user Object?

Comment: Here's a link to Apple's iOS Keychain Services guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html. Here's a open-source library that wraps Apple's Keychain APIs, making them easier to use for your use case: https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess.